# Nothing happens when I click the button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, python-datetime

This is a birthday calculator which is not working. The codes are:

```
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()
t.resizable(0, 0)
t.title("Birthday!!!")
t.geometry('380x200')

current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
current_date_lst = current_date.split('-')

v1 = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
v3 = StringVar()
l1 = Label(t, textvariable=v1).grid(row=1, column=1)
l2 = Label(t, textvariable=v2).grid(row=2, column=1)
l3 = Label(t, textvariable=v3).grid(row=4, column=1)

def starting():
    global v1, v2, v3, current_date, current_date_lst
    v1.set('❤Enter your birthday in yyyy-mm-dd format plz ❤')
    v2.set('❤And What is your name sweetie?❤')

    b_date = tkinter.Entry(t)
    b_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
    name = tkinter.Entry(t)
    name.grid(row=2, column=2)
    this = b_date.get()
    that = name.get()
    def haha():
        t.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda e: show_string(b_date, name))
        def show_string(b_date, name):
            this.split( '-' )
            if len(this)==3:
                if (current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]) == False:
                    v3.set('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')
                else:
                    age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(b_date[0])
                    v3.set("Congrats! {that} is {age} now!")
    def reset_now():
        result = b_date.get()
        length = len(result)
        b_date.delete(0, length)
        result2 = name.get()
        length2 = len(result2)
        name.delete(0, length2)
        v3.set('')      
    b2 = Button(text='Is it my Bday?', command=haha)
    b2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    b3 = Button(text='Reset', command=reset_now)
    b3.grid(row=3, column=2)

b1 = Button(text='Start', command=starting)
b1.grid(row=1, column=3)
mainloop()
```

Whenever I click the button `b2` it should show the result, but as I told you, nothing really happens. I tried different ways but none of them helped. What can I do in your opinion?

Comment: function `haha()` just binds the root window to a `<KeyRelease>` event and when that even is triggered it should execute that function but I would suggest no using too much nested functions and I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well none of the answers helped so I decided to solve it my self.

```
the_day = str(current_date_lst[14]) + str(current_date_lst[15])
the_month = str(current_date_lst[8]) + str(current_date_lst[9])
the_year = str(current_date_lst[2]) + str(current_date_lst[3])

def haha():
        this = str(b_date.get())
        that = name.get()
        def show_string():
            umm = this.split('-')
            if len(umm)==3:
                if the_month == umm[1] and the_day == umm[2]:
                    age = int(the_year) - int(umm[0])
                    tada = "Congrats! " + str(that) +  " is " +  str(age) +  " today!"
                    v3.set(tada)
                else:
                    v3.set('Nah, today is not your birthday:(')
            else:
                messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message='Enter ypu B-day completely')
```

With adding these lines, the program worked and there were no more trouble!

P.S: Yea I know the names of the variables are silly

Answer (score 0):

put `this = b_name.get()` and `that = name.get()` inside `haha()` because when `haha()` function run, the input data of `v1`, `v2` can be get. Second, you need to run the `show_string()` function, not `bind`. Replace `show_string(b_name, name)` with `show_string(this, that)` because `b_name`, `name` is a `Entry`, not string.

```
import datetime
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

t = Tk()
t.resizable(0, 0)
t.title("Birthday!!!")
t.geometry('380x200')

current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
current_date_lst = current_date.split('-')

v1 = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
v3 = StringVar()
l1 = Label(t, textvariable=v1).grid(row=1, column=1)
l2 = Label(t, textvariable=v2).grid(row=2, column=1)
l3 = Label(t, textvariable=v3).grid(row=4, column=1)

def starting():
    global v1, v2, v3, current_date, current_date_lst
    v1.set('❤Enter your birthday in yyyy-mm-dd format plz ❤')
    v2.set('❤And What is your name sweetie?❤')

    b_date = tkinter.Entry(t)
    b_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
    name = tkinter.Entry(t)
    name.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def haha():
        this = b_date.get()
        that = name.get()
        def show_string(b_date, name):
            nlist = this.split('-')
            if len(nlist)==3:
                if not (str(current_date_lst[1]) == str(nlist[1]) and 
                   str(current_date_lst[2]) == str(nlist[2])):
                   v3.set('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')
                else:
                    age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(nlist[0])
                    v3.set(f"Congrats! {that} is {age} now!")
       show_string(this,that)
    def reset_now():
        result = b_date.get()
        length = len(result)
        b_date.delete(0, length)
        result2 = name.get()
        length2 = len(result2)
        name.delete(0, length2)
        v3.set('')      
    b2 = Button(text='Is it my Bday?', command=haha)
    b2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    b3 = Button(text='Reset', command=reset_now)
    b3.grid(row=3, column=2)

b1 = Button(text='Start', command=starting)
b1.grid(row=1, column=3)
mainloop()
```

EDIT: My mistake is a `str(current_date_lst[1]) == str(this[1]) and str(current_date_lst[2]) == str(this[2])`, Im fixed now because `b_name` now the string, not list, and `else` function must be inside `if len(nlist)==3`.

Comment: Please explain what you have done, otherwise this answer has low value to future readers and stuff

Comment: first, the this, that value you call is early, you need to call it when your friend click a is it my birthday. second, you need to call the show_string function with this, that value, not b_name, name

Comment: first of I am not the OP, second add explanation to your post and that is not even a clear explanation

Comment: okay thanks for the comment, ill do it better.

Comment: you still haven't added explanation to your post, [edit] your post and add explanation

Comment: @Matiiss im not good at explant so much, can you check and show me what my mistake?

Comment: there is really no mistake, at least you now have added some explanation, great

Comment: Actually there are mistakes: 1) the `else` block inside `show_string()` should be same level as the inner `if`, i.e. `if not ...`; 2) `b_date` inside `show_string()` is a string (from `this`), not the result of `split()`, so comparing `current_date_list[x]` with `b_date[x]` is incorrect.  You need to compare `current_date_list[x]` with `lenght[x]` instead; 3) using `this`  and `that` inside `show_string()` is not appropriate as they are actually passed as argument `b_date` and `name`.

Comment: @acw1668 sorry that my mistake, im fixed now and had testing it again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just simply execute whatever you need and not bind anything (at least you haven't specified why this needs to be bound to anything):

```py
def haha():
    this.split('-')
    if len(this) == 3:
        if (current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]) == False:
            v3.set('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')
        else:
            age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(b_date[0])
            v3.set("Congrats! {that} is {age} now!")
```

also you know, right, that this: `this.split('-')` returns a list which means that not assigning it to anything does nothing so you could try something like this (to not change much):

```py
this = this.split('-')
```

also why don't you just do sth like this:

```py
if current_date == b_date.get():
```

a simple comparison no need to split anything,

also I noticed this issue:

```py
b_date = tkinter.Entry(t)
b_date.grid(row=1, column=2)
name = tkinter.Entry(t)
name.grid(row=2, column=2)
this = b_date.get()
that = name.get()
```

you create Entries, then grid them and immediately try to get their value, how do you think that is going to work? you need to use `.get()` after user has inputed something otherwise you just get an empty string,

also:

```py
b_date[1]
```

and the similar lines will raise an error since I am pretty sure that `tkinter` widgets don't have an attribute `2`

Answer (score 0):

The function `haha` just binds `t` to `KeyRelease`. And, `show_string` is just defined inside it. You have to actually call the function.

```
    def haha():
        
        def show_string(b_date, name):
            this.split( '-' )
            if len(this)==3:
                if (current_date_lst[1] == b_date[1] and current_date_lst[2] == b_date[2]) == False:
                    v3.set('Sorry, today is not your birthday:(')
                else:
                    age = int(current_date_lst[0]) - int(b_date[0])
                    v3.set("Congrats! {that} is {age} now!")
        show_string(b_date.get(), name.get())
```

Comment: the bind should call the function when the event is triggered so that part is already done, the issue I think is that the event doesn't get triggered not that the function is not called

Comment: None of the answers were useful :(